# How to connect to Oracle Database 12c HR schema from IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am new in Oracle Database. I have successfully done these:

1. Installed and configured Oracle Database 12c in Windows 10 VMware virtual machine.
2. Connected to HR schema from SQL*PLUS, SQL Developer, Navicat.
3. Created a ASP.NET web application project and connected to HR schema from Visual Studio 2015.

Now I want to connect to HR schema through JDBC from IntelliJ IDEA 14. Unfortunately I cannot connect though I have installed JDBC drivers. I have read the reference [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-a-db-data-source.html) but it does not work. I am getting the following error:

```
Connection to Oracle - HR@localhost failed
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    ...
```

For better demonstration, a screenshot is attached. Notice that I cannot define the service name (in this case **"pdborcl"**) because there is no text field for this in *Data Sources and Drivers* window. Also notice that I can still connect to HR schema through SQL*PLUS *after* the error.

How to resolve this issue? Or, is it an IntelliJ IDEA bug or a JDBC bug?

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Oracle Database HR schema connection failure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using "pdborcl" in the Database field. That is your service name, HR is just a schema in it.

Comment: I thought that *Database* field is just for any name. Thank you.

Comment: It is confusing, I agree. Probably that page in IDEA was originally designed to serve multiple database-types, and this generic "Database" fields fitted the rest of the DB providers better.